# Drawing Issue with ACEDrawingView

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to implement fast forward functionality using ACEDrawing. What I am doing is when user is drawing any drawing at that time I record all points from which used draw a line. So after user finished its Drawing, I will have all points from which used draw line. So I want develop fast forward functionality in which user will click on one button to see the final drawing. I have implemented code as shown below. It works fine for Small drawing that is for say 2000 points. But When points increases to 1000000 and above it crashed. I don't know how it handle this. Can any buddy give suggestion on this?

Code:

```
    self.currentTool = ACEDrawingToolTypePen;
    self.currentTool.lineWidth = self.lineWidth;
    self.currentTool.lineColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.currentTool.lineAlpha = 1;
    [self.currentTool setInitialPoint:currentPoint];
    [self.pathArray addObject:self.currentTool];
    currentPointArray = [mainDictionary objectForKey:@"points"];
    for (int j = 2; j<[currentPointArray count]; j++) {

         currentPoint = CGPointMake([[[currentPointArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue]*widMul, [[[currentPointArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue]*heiMul);

         previousPoint2 = CGPointMake([[[currentPointArray objectAtIndex:j-2] objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue]*widMul, [[[currentPointArray objectAtIndex:j-2] objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue]*heiMul);
         previousPoint1 = CGPointMake([[[currentPointArray objectAtIndex:j-1] objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue]*widMul, [[[currentPointArray objectAtIndex:j-1] objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue]*heiMul);
         if ([self.currentTool isKindOfClass:[ACEDrawingPenTool class]]) {

              CGRect bounds = [(ACEDrawingPenTool*)self.currentTool addPathPreviousPreviousPoint:previousPoint2 withPreviousPoint:previousPoint1 withCurrentPoint:currentPoint];
              CGRect drawBox = bounds;
              drawBox.origin.x -= self.lineWidth * 1.0;
              drawBox.size.width += self.lineWidth * 2.0;
              drawBox.size.height += self.lineWidth * 2.0;
              [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:drawBox];
        }
        [self updateCacheImage:NO];
}
```

Comment: I don't want upvote on this , i really stuck with this..need help seriously.

Comment: You are aware that even with just a CGPoint the data structure will consume 16 Megabytes of memory on a 64-bit device? If you store 3 points plus any additional data (ie boxing points in NSValue for example or instances of a class containing the point) the memory usage may be several factors higher. If it crashes, let us know what the crash is (error message, console log) and check if you receive any memory warnings shortly before.

Comment: Yes, i am getting crash with message:Terminated due to Memory Pressure.

Comment: draw fewer points, one million is more than a lot. And optimize memory usage of the points you store, ie make a custom point struct using int16_t data types

Comment: my code works fine for lesser points but it only causes problem with more points...n i got little bit with int16_t data types, i will try to use that.

Comment: I think storing that much data is not causing any problem. So Data structure is not the issue i guess.Though i will try int16_t.

Comment: you think? You get a memory pressure related crash when number of points is extremely large, that's a pretty strong indicator that your algorithm and data allocate too much memory to handle this many points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're having memory issues.

You can change your code as follows.
In your `updateCacheImage` method, you need to put your `imageContext` in `AutoReleaspool` to free up your memory.

```
@autoreleasepool {

    // init a context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

    //End Context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

You also have to set your objects to `nil` for making your memory free, like this:

```
id object;
object = nil;
```